# How do i know the hostname of my NTP server?

Tags: ntp

I set up a NTP server on my windows machine using the Meinberg Ntp server setup.

I think I have it working, but where do I find the name of the server so I can add it to the config file of the device I want to sync to the server?

Comment: Shouldn't it just be the hostname or IP of your Windows machine ?

Comment: Is it? Haha, that would certainly make it easy.

Comment: You access all network services a Computer hosts by its hostname or IP, independent of the protocol. Some services can also be registered in the DNS but I think your network is too small for that.

Comment: Thanks! I had no idea it was like that. Should I delete this question since it is so minor/obvious?

Comment: I can put up with getting credits for an answer, so I added one ;-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You access all network services a computer hosts by its hostname or IP, independent of the protocol. Some services can also be registered in the DNS to make them "discoverable" but normally only networks of a certain size justify the effort involved in setting this up.

Simply determine the hostname of your computer and specify this as the ntp host on your device you want to sync. Perhaps the easiest way to get to the hostname is pressing `lWindows` + `[Pause/Break][1]`, which shows you the [system properties](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/839573). Should work on most current Windows OSs.